# Historical inventory by day

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql and have a table where we log inventory orders. The table (a simplification) looks like this:

```
||id|ordered_date |Date  |itemid| status    ||
||1 |Jan-4        |Jan-4 | a    | ordered   ||
||2 |Jan-6        |Jan-6 | b    | ordered   ||
||3 |Jan-8        |Jan-8 | c    | ordered   ||
||4 |Jan-8        |Jan-9 | c    | shipped   ||
||4 |Jan-6        |Jan-9 | b    | shipped   ||
||4 |Jan-4        |Jan-10| a    | shipped   ||
```

What we want is the total number of orders per day that have not yet shipped, so something like this:

```
date  | inventory
Jan-4 |    1
Jan-5 |    1
Jan-6 |    2
Jan-7 |    2
Jan-8 |    3
Jan-9 |    1
Jan-10|    0
```

I can find the total number of unshipped orders on any single day using a query like this:

```
select count(*) from inventory where 
    status = "Shipped" AND 
    date > "Jan-8" AND 
    ordered_date <= "Jan-8"
```

But we need the number of orders for all days. And the above query has a problem in that it won't find orders that have not shipped yet. So, any help would be appreciated.

(assume the date column is a valid SQL date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(*)
FROM inventory 
WHERE status != 'shipped'
GROUP BY date ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: That works! Much easier than I thought it would be. I don't know what I was thinking. Thanks.